How to embed link using Linkedin post API
when I post and added link using Linkedin post appeared as EmbededLink using Linkedin
but when posting using post API post appeared without embed image post added using post api
Post API returns successful. it displays content but not feed embed image. do we need to provide any other information through payload.
I tried above steps. How to do this using Linkedin Marketing API
